# Using Python's select.poll() to demonstrate asynchronous write of multiple files

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous

I am trying to build a sample Python script to see myself how can I asynchronously write multiple files at once using select.poll() in python 3.5 and compare the performance with the synchronous version.
I'm testing it on a BSD system.

However, it seems I am still doing it synchronously and I cannot see where I'm making a mistake, or how to debug the script.

Here's my code so far

```
import os
import fcntl
import select
poll = select.poll()

big_text = open('big-text.txt', 'r').read()

files_data = {}

for i in range(FILES_NO):
    file_name = 'data/file_{}'.format(i)
    fd = open(file_name, 'w')
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL | os.O_NONBLOCK)

    files_data[fd.fileno()] = {}
    files_data[fd.fileno()]['fd'] = fd
    files_data[fd.fileno()]['bytes_wrote'] = 0
    files_data[fd.fileno()]['filename'] = file_name

    poll.register(fd)

def write(files_data, fileno, text):
    files_data[fileno]['fd'].write(text)
    files_data[fileno]['bytes_wrote'] += len(text)

chunk_size = 8192

while True:
    polled = poll.poll(0)

    if not polled:
        break

    for fileno, flags in polled:
        if flags & select.POLLOUT:
            bytes_wrote = files_data[fileno]['bytes_wrote']
            file_name = files_data[fileno]['filename']

            next_chunk = big_text[bytes_wrote:bytes_wrote + chunk_size]
            write(files_data, fileno, next_chunk)

            if len(next_chunk) == 0:
                poll.unregister(fileno)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First off it doesn't work for file descriptors that are going to disk. you generally only use for network fd'.

Comment: @self, thanks for your comment, this is a very interesting information. However, it seems hard to find. Just curious, can you confirm that with a source?